# What's the standard way to load the source model of product attributes, with respect to the default source model?

Tags: product-attribute, eav, source-model

I have a product attribute with type "select", for example "manufacturer". No source model is defined, so Magento uses the default source model, defined in `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity`:

```
const DEFAULT_SOURCE_MODEL      = 'eav/entity_attribute_source_config';
```

But with this code:

```
$manufacturerAttribute = Mage::getModel('catalog/entity_attribute')
    ->loadByCode(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, 'manufacturer');
$values = $manufacturerAttribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();
```

I get this exception:

> Source model "" not found for attribute "manufacturer"

Tracing down the error, I found that the default source model is actually fetched in `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Abstract` with:

```
protected function _getDefaultSourceModel()
{
    return $this->getEntity()->getDefaultAttributeSourceModel();
}
```

and:

```
/**
 * Retrieve entity instance
 *
 * @return Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract
 */
public function getEntity()
{
    if (!$this->_entity) {
        $this->_entity = $this->getEntityType();
    }
    return $this->_entity;
}
```

This looks all fine in the IDE but when I debug, I notice that `getEntity` actually returns an object of `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Type` which does **not** have a `getDefaultAttributeSourceModel()` method, unlike `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract`. Looks like a bug in Magento to me...

What makes it even more confusing, is that `_getDefaultSourceModel()` is overridden in `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute`:

```
/**
 * Get default attribute source model
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function _getDefaultSourceModel()
{
    return 'eav/entity_attribute_source_table';
}
```

But since `$attribute->getResource()` always gives me an instance of `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute`, I don't know how to make use of this.

**I know that I could define the source model explicitly in an update script and that's how I usually handle it, but there has to be a proper way to make use of the default source model, I just can't figure it out.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not exactly an answer, but a little long winded to be a comment...

I'd have to agree, that this is indeed a bug, or perhaps it should be framed as an 'unfinished feature'. As such I don't personally believe there is a 'proper way'. Since saving a new attribute model will set the source_model field (in `Mage_Eav_Model_Resource_Entity_Attribute::_beforeSave`) it *should* be impossible to create a new attribute without a source_model. Therefore it's arguably a bug in `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup::_insertAttribute`, which creates rows in the database directly, allowing for empty values in that column.

Another interesting observation is that `getDefaultAttributeSourceModel` returns `eav/entity_attribute_source_config`, whereas the value injected by `_beforeSave` is `eav/entity_attribute_source_table` (which falls inline with the default you saw in the catalog attribute). Comparing the two models, the former is actually pretty useless in itself. The docblock for the class points out that it should really be abstract, which seems to be the case. Unless 2 protected members (`_options` and `_configNodePath`) have a value, the class will always throw an exception `Failed to load node %s from config`. The latter however will look in the table eav_attribute_option_value, which sounds much more useful.

The closest I can get to an answer aside from 'fixing' the database, is to manually do what the `_beforeSave` would have done:

```
$manufacturerAttribute = Mage::getModel('catalog/entity_attribute')
    ->loadByCode(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, 'manufacturer');
if ( ! $manufacturerAttribute->getSourceModel()) {
    $manufacturerAttribute->setSourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_source_table')
}
$values = $manufacturerAttribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();
```

Apologies if there's any false syllogisms here, it's getting late.

Comment: "As such I don't personally believe there is a 'proper way'." - I already feared so, thanks for your additional insights.